# Where to download developer version of CQ5

Tags: adobe, aem

I am new to CQ.
I wanted to install CQ in my home PC.
Is a developer version of CQ is available ? Something like JSK in fatwire?
Where it can be downloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding you will need to attend Developer training OR work for a company currently utilizing CQ5 in order to have a license for a local instance.